# SQL Server Query LEFT JOIN, SUM and GROUP BY and I'm stumped!

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, sum

I am beating my brain against this one

I have 3 SQL Server 2005 tables

**userawards**:

```
id, awardamount, userid, dateawarded, awardtypeid
```

**user:**

```
id, firstname, lastname
```

**awardtypes:**

```
id, title
```

So if the `awards` table had the rows

```
1, 300.00, 3, 01-01-2011, 1
2, 125.00, 3, 01-05-2011, 1
3,  50.00, 2, 01-05-2011, 2
```

user table rows

```
1, john, smith
2, mark, smith
3, bob, smith
```

award types

```
1, cash
2, prize
```

and I want the output to look similar to this

```
bob smith, 425.00, cash
mark smith, 50, prize
```

etc etc.

A user can have multiple awards, the results need to display unique users, but with there total award amount. in addition there needs to be 2 joins, one, to grab the users first name/last that's in a user table and the award type title.

So my query is looking like this (i know it doesn't work)

```
SELECT id, userid, awardtypeid, SUM(awardamount) 
FROM awards a
LEFT JOIN userinfo ui ON ui.userid = a,userid
LEFT JOIN awardtypes ON awardtypesid = a.awardtypeid
GROUP BY userid
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: If a user has multiple of awards of different types, what should be the expected output?

Comment: It would help to show us some sample inputs and expected outputs. Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: You have a , in stead of . In a,userid

Comment: revised the question to answer your questions ;)

Comment: You said in your description that you want unique users (or one row per user). However, you have included award type and later said that you also want "the" award type title. That would imply one row per user, per award type (of the awards they have received).

Comment: @Sherdog - Add another row to your inputs for a user receiving another award of a different type (e.g., `(4, 123.00, 2, 01-05-2011, 1)`). What should the output be?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably want

```
SELECT userid, 
       awardtypeid, 
       SUM(awardamount) 
FROM   awards a 
       LEFT JOIN userinfo ui 
         ON ui.userid = a.userid 
       LEFT JOIN awardtypes 
         ON awardtypesid = a.awardtypeid 
GROUP  BY userid, 
          awardtypeid
```

or

```
SELECT userid, 
       SUM(awardamount) 
FROM   awards a 
       LEFT JOIN userinfo ui 
         ON ui.userid = a.userid 
       LEFT JOIN awardtypes 
         ON awardtypesid = a.awardtypeid 
GROUP  BY userid
```

This drops the id Column (probably not what you want to group on)

In the first case I included the awardtypeid in the select but this means you must also add that to the group by.

Comment: I'd vote but i don't have the rep yet.. but yes this solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for the ability to glean what the heck was desired from what was given (and for the answer).

Comment: Thanks conrad, I have accepted your answer :) thanks for the heads up on that.. I looked right past the checkmark.  And yes thanks for providing the answer with my bad attempt at explaining the situaiton :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but the way you do it now is that it will show the number of awardamount, or bactually, the sum of awardamount - but per id, user, awardtypeid combination. You need to grab the user and sum of awards by itself, then join up with awardtype id - just be aware that the sum of award amounts is repeated for every awardtypeid

```
SELECT 
     ??.id ,
     a.userid , 
     a.awardtypeid , 
     ab.awardamount ,
     <whateverelse>
FROM 
     (select userid, SUM(awardamount) as awardamount FROM awards GROUP BY userid) AS ab
INNER JOIN awards AS a on ab.userid = a.userid
LEFT JOIN userinfo AS ui  
  ON ui.userid = a.userid
LEFT JOIN awardtypes AS at 
  ON awardtypesid = a.awardtypeid
```

By adding up the sum of awardamount per user before you join it in, you should be able to get what you want, without any grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ui.FirstName
 ,ui.LastName
 ,at.Title AS Award
 ,SUM(a.AwardAmount) AS AwardAmount
FROM Awards a
  INNER JOIN UserInfo ui ON ui.UserId = a.UserId
  INNER JOIN AwardTypes at ON at.AwardTypeId = a.AwardTypeId
GROUP BY ui.FirstName, ui.LastName, at.Title
ORDER BY ui.LastName, ui.FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, there should be no more than one row per user and you need a total award amount per user.
On other side you want to know what kind of awards every user had.
You can show comma delimited list of awards for every user:

```
select 
    usr.FirstName,
    usr.LastName, 
    awd.AwardAmount,
    AwardTypes = (   
        select Title + ','
        from UserAwards uaw
            join AwardTypes awt on
                uaw.AwardTypeId = awt.Id
        where uaw.UserId = usr.id
        for xml path(''))
from [User] usr
    join (
        select UserId, sum(AwardAmount) AwardAmount
        from UserAwards uaw
        group by UserId
    ) awd on
        awd.UserId = usr.Id
```