# Sql with Left Join, aggregate Sum and Group By

Tags: sql

This is NOT a duplicate of [SQL Server Query LEFT JOIN, SUM and GROUP BY and I'm stumped!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873205/sql-server-query-left-join-sum-and-group-by-and-im-stumped).  Please don't mark duplicate just because of the similarities in the titles.

Assume I have a table **STARTING_QUARTERBACK** with columns **PLAYER_ID** (int), **TEAM** (int).  I also have another table **QUARTERBACK** with columns **PLAYER_ID** (int), **LAST_NAME** (varchar 20), **FIRST_NAME** (varchar 20), and a table called **STATISTICS** with columns **PLAYER_ID** (int), **GAME_DATE** (DateTime), **TOUCHDOWN** (int), **PASSING_YARD** (int).

```
STARTING_QUARTERBACK
    PLAYER_ID      int
    TEAM           int

QUARTERBACK
    PLAYER_ID      int
    LAST_NAME      varchar 20
    FIRST_NAME     varchar 20

STATISTICS
    PLAYER_ID      int
    GAME_DATE      DateTime
    TOUCHDOWN      int
    PASSING_YARDS  int
```

I would like to write a query to select all quarterbacks who are NOT a starter but have thrown more than a combined of more than 10 touchdowns or more 1000 yards of all the games in 2009.

The result should list 1 row per quarterback who meets the conditions and his aggregated TDs and passing yards in 2009.

I am getting multiple rows per quarterback where each row shows the individual stat from each game in 2009 which is not I really want.  I want the aggregate.  What would be the correct SQL?

**EDIT** Having included my code is meant to clarify not to confuse, but it seems to have the reverse effect, so I just removed the code.  The question can be summarized as follow: Pretend the NFL hands you the above 3 tables and asks you to list all non-starting QBs who did well in 2009 and show their combined TDs and passing yards for that year.  The NFL doesn't care about individual games, just the total.  Definition of 'doing well' is more than 10 TDs or 1000 yards.

Comment: I think you want to `GROUP by QUARTERBACK.PLAYER_ID order by QUARTERBACK.PLAYER_ID` rather than just order by.

Comment: @Dan: GROUP by QUARTERBACK.PLAYER_ID is there.  You can just ignore that order by, it won't matter to what I am trying to ask.

Comment: This code is so verbose, I have no inclination to read it. Please use short aliases instead of full table names.

Comment: Ahh sorry, didn't see that. Are you sure that group by works since starting_quarterback.team shouldn't exist? Can't you just group by player id?
Also, your `sum(STATISTICS.PASSING_YARD < 1000)` has bad parens and I'm not sure why you filter on game date in your having rather than in the join.

Comment: @Khnle - please do not remove the SQL. It was the wall of text style of your SQL statement that was confusing, not the fact that you had it there. Without the SQL you are missing vital details people need to see in order to help you, you will get better and more answers with it than without it. And without it you run the risk of your question being closed as not answerable. I have rolled it back, you will need to re-enter any further text that you had edited in.

Comment: @slugster:  I see your point. But everyone seems to be focused on that code instead of what is being asked, it seems like.  I think the question is very answerable for anyone who is SQL experts because the question is clear and it is a real-world situation.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without looking at the data.
I think the problem might be the group by. Try these two changes:

- Remove the STARTING_QUARTERBACK.TEAM from the group by. You are not looking for people in the STARTING_QUARTERBACK. Remove it from the SELECT as well. It will be always NULL
- Remove the condition "STATISTICS.GAME_DATE >= '2009-01-01' and STATISTICS.GAME_DATE < '2010-01-01'" from the HAVING  you are already filtering in the WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
player_id, sum(touchdown) total_touchdowns, sum(passing_yard) total_yardage
from quaterback q, statistics s
where q.player_id = s.player_id
and q.player_id not in (select player_id from starting_quarterback)
group by player_id
having sum(touchdown) > 10, sum(passing_yard) > 1000
```

**or**

```
select * from
(
    select 
    player_id, sum(touchdown) total_touchdowns, sum(passing_yard) total_yardage
    from quaterback q, statistics s
    where q.player_id = s.player_id
    and q.player_id not in (select player_id from starting_quarterback)
    group by player_id
)
where total_touchdows > 10 and total_yardage > 1000
```

Comment: Thanks.  Haven't posted much and didn't know how to block format... and didn't feel like messing with it too long ;)